Requirements of working in KSA for my wife
I have an offer from a Saudi company. I will travel to KSA in the next days.
My wife will follow me as a dependent within the next three months.
In the meanwhile, she will be looking for a job and here I see a complexity in how to proceed because there are many paths.

She come as dependent w/o a job and when she arrives she start looking for a job
She can find a job before travel to KSA and here she travels as a new employee.

These are the two ways I see it. I'm not sure however about the regulations and policies for this situation.
I appreciate any input or material to read about this.
